# How to Click "mdl-layout--fixed-header" Menu Button Programatically

Tags: material-design-lite

I have a button that I want to open the mdl-layout__drawer.  For example, see the [official example here](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html) and note the menu icon opens the drawer upon clicking.

I have a button that, upon clicking, I want the drawer to open.  I have tried both of the jQuery selectors below with the jQuery.click() method.  Neither works - only a screen flicker.  Any ideas?

```
$(".mdl-layout__drawer-button").click();
$(".material-icons:contains('menu')").click();
```

Comment: Any chance you could share a codepen where the issue is visible? There is a number of things that could be going wrong, so it's hard to tell without more code to look at.

Comment: [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/epzwOO)  Ummm, ...well, it works on Codepen!  Hmmm...

Comment: It could be a problem with loading jQuery, in that case. Sadly, I'm not an expert there, so I don't think I'll be able to help further without a failing example :-/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is inside `$(document).on('pageinit')` and you are using the correct selector to detect the button click like in the example below:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
        $("#idOfTheButton").click(function() {
            $(".mdl-layout__drawer-button").click();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to click the menu button, toggle sidenav visibility with material API
`document.querySelector('.mdl-layout').MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();`